# how to properly use the method isSignedIn() from google_sign_in.dart in flutter/dart

Tags: flutter, google-signin

I dont know how to call in the right way a a method called isSignedIn() defined in [google_sign_in.dart]

May you help me with how to call this method in correct way? I am logged in an I would like to run in onPressed in RaisedButton and display result on console.

what I tried was:

```
RaisedButton(
  child: const Text('REFRESH'),
  onPressed: () {
    print(_googleSignIn.isSignedIn());
  },
),
```

but I got `I/flutter ( 4093): Instance of 'Future<bool>'` on console.

Thx a lot.
P.

Answer (score 1):

First of all `_googleSignIn.isSignedIn()` is a future bool value. So, try using it with `async` keywords.

```
RaisedButton(
  child: const Text('REFRESH'),
  onPressed: () async {
    bool isSignedIn = await _googleSignIn.isSignedIn();
    print(isSignedIn);
  },
),
```

This way you can check whether you are signed in or not using google.

Comment: Jay, 
thank you for your answer,  it helped and it works now. I really appreciate your prompt help.  

If I would ask an additional question this method depends on local apps information about the user status Logged or not, is this right?  

So this method doesn't tell me if a user lost access after I remotely log out this user using google account site?  

May you advise which solution should I consider if I would like to test move the user back to the login screen after the user was log out remotely?